# there is a gap between the content layout and navigationbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have installed a application from `Google play`, but something wrong when I try to hide the `navigationbar`.

more details like blow:

Issue list:

- a gap between `Application` content and `navigationbar`
- `Application` content can't adjust when I hide `navigationbar`

[image]

Issue already exist When I landscape ,like below:

issue list:

- a gap between `Application` content and `navigationbar`
- `Application` content cann't adjust when I hide `navigationbar`
- system bar time out of boundary

[image]

**Question:**

- How can I remove the gap?
- How can I dynamic adjust the application content when I hide `navigationbar` bar?
- Why time out of boundary?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

</Toolbar>
```